# even (n + m) -> even n /\ even m \/ odd n /\ odd m

Tags: coq

How can I prove this lemma:

```
 Lemma even_plus_split n m :
 even (n + m) -> even n /\ even m \/ odd n /\ odd m.
```

These are the only libraries and definition that can be used:

```
 Require Import Arith.
 Require Import Coq.omega.Omega.

 Definition even (n: nat) := exists k, n = 2 * k.
 Definition odd  (n: nat) := exists k, n = 2 * k + 1.
```

I am new to Coq and confused about it. Can you give me a solution? Thanks in advance!

the code so far:

```
 Lemma even_plus_split n m :
   even (n + m) -> even n /\ even m \/ odd n /\ odd m.
 Proof.
   intros.
   unfold even.
   unfold even in H.
   destruct H as [k H].
   unfold odd.
   exists (1/2*k).
```

result so far:

```
 1 subgoal
 n, m, k : nat
 H : n + m = 2 * k
 ______________________________________(1/1)
 (exists k0 : nat, n = 2 * k0) /\ (exists k0 : nat, m = 2 * k0) \/
 (exists k0 : nat, n = 2 * k0 + 1) /\ (exists k0 : nat, m = 2 * k0 + 1)
```

I just want to make k0 equals to 1/2*k, and therefore I suppose it would make sense, but I can't do that.

Comment: Can you share the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: `Lemma even_plus_split n m :
  even (n + m) -> even n /\ even m \/ odd n /\ odd m.
Proof.
intros.
unfold even.
unfold even in H.
destruct H as [k H].
unfold odd.
exists (1/2*k)`

Comment: Try to do induction on `n`, but first generalize with respect to `m`.  Like this, for instance: `revert m; induction n; intros m Heven.`  Then you get an induction hypothesis that you can use.  I guess this is a school exercise so I'd rather not give the full solution here...

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to make k0 equals to 1/2*k, and therefore I suppose it would make sense, but I can't do that.

There is a function called `Nat.div2`, which divides a natural number by 2.  Running `Search Nat.div2.`

```
Nat.le_div2: forall n : nat, Nat.div2 (S n) <= n
Nat.lt_div2: forall n : nat, 0 < n -> Nat.div2 n < n
Nat.div2_decr: forall a n : nat, a <= S n -> Nat.div2 a <= n
Nat.div2_wd: Morphisms.Proper (Morphisms.respectful eq eq) Nat.div2
Nat.div2_spec: forall a : nat, Nat.div2 a = Nat.shiftr a 1
Nnat.N2Nat.inj_div2: forall a : N, N.to_nat (N.div2 a) = Nat.div2 (N.to_nat a)
Nnat.Nat2N.inj_div2: forall n : nat, N.of_nat (Nat.div2 n) = N.div2 (N.of_nat n)
Nat.div2_double: forall n : nat, Nat.div2 (2 * n) = n
Nat.div2_div: forall a : nat, Nat.div2 a = a / 2
Nat.div2_succ_double: forall n : nat, Nat.div2 (S (2 * n)) = n
Nat.div2_odd: forall a : nat, a = 2 * Nat.div2 a + Nat.b2n (Nat.odd a)
Nat.div2_bitwise:
  forall (op : bool -> bool -> bool) (n a b : nat),
  Nat.div2 (Nat.bitwise op (S n) a b) = Nat.bitwise op n (Nat.div2 a) (Nat.div2 b)
```

Of these, the most promising seems to be `Nat.div2_odd: forall a : nat, a = 2 * Nat.div2 a + Nat.b2n (Nat.odd a)`.  If you `pose proof` this lemma, you can `destruct (Nat.odd a)` and use `simpl` to get that either `a = 2 * Nat.div2 a` or `a = 2 * Nat.div2 a + 1`, for whichever `a` you choose.

This may not give you a solution directly (I am not convinced that setting `k0` to `k / 2` is the right decision), but if it does not, you should make sure that you can figure out how to prove this fact on paper before you try it in Coq.  Coq is very good at making sure that you don't make any jumps of logic that you're not allowed to make; it's *extremely* bad at helping you figure out how to prove a fact that you don't yet know how to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody who tries to answer seems to be dancing around the fact that you actually chose a wrong direction for this proof.  Here is a example:

if n = 601 and m = 399, then n + m = 2 * 500,
  n = 2 * 300 + 1, and m = 2 * 199 + 1.

Between 500, 300, and 199, the 1/2 ratio does not appear anywhere.

Still the statement (even n /\ even m) / (odd n /\ odd m) is definitely true.

So for now, you have more a math problem than a Coq problem.

You have to make a proof for universally quantified numbers `n` and `m`, but somehow this proof should also work for specific choices of these numbers.  So in a sense you can make the mental exercise of testing your proof on examples.